# MongoDB Fatal Assertion 16167 on startup

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting a Fatal Assertion 16167 error message while starting the MongoDB 3.0.7 server. I searched online but couldn't find any suggestions. My log is as below. Please help me in solving this error. Note that it was working fine earlier. KB2731284 is already installed. mongod.lock file also has been deleted.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nagadeep>mongod --journal --dbpath="d:\data\db"
2016-06-19T20:35:07.553+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not
installed, will zero-out data files
2016-06-19T20:35:07.553+0530 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdow
n - d:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
2016-06-19T20:35:07.584+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=d:\data\db\j
ournal
2016-06-19T20:35:07.585+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover begin
2016-06-19T20:35:07.585+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] info no lsn file in jour
nal/ directory
2016-06-19T20:35:07.585+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover lsn: 0
2016-06-19T20:35:07.585+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover d:\data\db\journ
al\j._0
2016-06-19T20:35:07.586+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
2016-06-19T20:35:07.586+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2016-06-19T20:35:07.640+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover done
2016-06-19T20:35:07.640+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] preallocating a journal
file d:\data\db\journal\prealloc.0
2016-06-19T20:35:09.560+0530 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2016-06-19T20:35:09.562+0530 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread s
tarted
2016-06-19T20:35:09.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3
544 port=27017 dbpath=d:\data\db 32-bit host=Lapaka-Tapaka
2016-06-19T20:35:09.608+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-19T20:35:09.610+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bi
t MongoDB binary.
2016-06-19T20:35:09.612+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds a
re limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
2016-06-19T20:35:09.615+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       See http://doch
ub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
2016-06-19T20:35:09.616+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-19T20:35:09.618+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows XP
SP3
2016-06-19T20:35:09.620+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.4
2016-06-19T20:35:09.622+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 0481c958dae
b2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5
2016-06-19T20:35:09.624+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.
getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Servic
e Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-06-19T20:35:09.629+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-06-19T20:35:09.631+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { db
Path: "d:\data\db", journal: { enabled: true } } }
2016-06-19T20:35:09.695+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MapViewOfFileEx for d:/d
ata/db/test.0 failed with error errno:8 Not enough storage is available to proce
ss this command. (file size is 67108864) in MemoryMappedFile::createPrivateMap
2016-06-19T20:35:09.695+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 16167
2016-06-19T20:35:10.707+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\util\log.cpp(135)                                           mongo::logContex
t+0xa4
2016-06-19T20:35:10.708+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\util\assert_util.cpp(165)                                   mongo::fassertFa
iled+0x8f
2016-06-19T20:35:10.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\util\mmap_win.cpp(405)                                      mongo::MemoryMap
pedFile::createPrivateMap+0x256
2016-06-19T20:35:10.710+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\durable_mapped_file.cpp(272)             mongo::DurableMa
ppedFile::finishOpening+0x18c
2016-06-19T20:35:10.711+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\durable_mapped_file.cpp(264)             mongo::DurableMa
ppedFile::create+0x101
2016-06-19T20:35:10.721+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\data_file.cpp(178)                       mongo::DataFile:
:open+0x167
2016-06-19T20:35:10.722+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp(243)          mongo::MmapV1Ext
entManager::_addAFile+0x19d
2016-06-19T20:35:10.732+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp(401)          mongo::MmapV1Ext
entManager::_createExtent+0x8d
2016-06-19T20:35:10.733+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp(188)          mongo::MmapV1Ext
entManager::init+0x28a
2016-06-19T20:35:10.742+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_database_catalog_entry.cpp(180)  mongo::MMAPV1Dat
abaseCatalogEntry::MMAPV1DatabaseCatalogEntry+0x174
2016-06-19T20:35:10.743+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_engine.cpp(272)                  mongo::MMAPV1Eng
ine::getDatabaseCatalogEntry+0x178
2016-06-19T20:35:10.783+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\catalog\database_holder.cpp(128)                         mongo::DatabaseH
older::openDb+0x1b3
2016-06-19T20:35:10.784+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\db.cpp(373)                                              mongo::repairDat
abasesAndCheckVersion+0x444
2016-06-19T20:35:10.802+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\db.cpp(549)                                              mongo::_initAndL
isten+0xc5c
2016-06-19T20:35:10.803+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\db.cpp(649)                                              mongo::initAndLi
sten+0x40
2016-06-19T20:35:10.804+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\db.cpp(896)                                              mongoDbMain+0x1d
8
2016-06-19T20:35:10.805+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
ngo\db\db.cpp(693)                                              wmain+0x4b
2016-06-19T20:35:10.806+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vcto
ols\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c(255)                              __tmainCRTStartu
p+0xfe
2016-06-19T20:35:10.807+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] kernel32.dll
                                                                BaseThreadInitTh
unk+0x12
2016-06-19T20:35:10.808+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ntdll.dll
                                                                RtlInitializeExc
eptionChain+0xef
2016-06-19T20:35:10.809+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-19T20:35:10.810+0530 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Comment: How much memory do you have. I see error `Not enough storage is available to proce ss this command. (file size is 67108864) in MemoryMappedFile::createPrivateMap`

Comment: Have you installed the Windows KB2731284 update? Looks like that's the problem.

Comment: @Saleem, There're no memory issues. It was working fine till the previous launch. And I've not added any data when I launched last time. This is basically a DB instance used for learning by me.

Comment: @YakovL The update has been installed and system was restarted before getting this error.

Comment: See.  https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-13910

Comment: Also. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mongodb-user/H1AFYQk0RZE

Comment: @Nagadeep so is it possible that the update actually caused the error?

Comment: @Saleem Thanks so much! The Google Groups link that you shared solved my problem. It was actually an issue with one of the DBs. Upon deleting the same, I could progress further. I've tested this on Windows 10 32-bit too and is working well. Please post the Google Groups link as an answer so that I can accept the same.

Comment: @YakovL Windows KB2731284 Update installation had no impact. The issue was occurring even before the update was installed.